# Deploying standalone python script to web server with html input

Tags: python, html

I have a standalone python script that I currently run from the command line, that I would like to use from a static webpage. I've currently deployed it to heroku, and can run it from console in a dyno, but that's as far as I've gotten.

My script takes .txt files as input, and generates a .csv file as output. I would like to use the  tag to request the input file from the user on a form page, pass that file to the python script and execute the script, then make the output file available for user download.

I realize this is a broad question, so I'm not really asking for a step by step solution, but rather an overview of how this needs to be handled, and maybe some links to appropriate docs/tutorials. I've been searching google for hours, but most of the results are framework based webapp tutorials, which is not what I need at this time.

Cheers

Comment: If you don't want a framework, then you want a [CGI script](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)

Comment: You can use php with exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php